# Read/write /etc with read-only filesystem

Tags: readonly, etc

I have a setup for an embedded project where I'd like to keep the root filesystem read-only and system configuration on a read/write partition.  Users cannot install programs, but they can modify configurations.  Most of this is fairly easy except for the `/etc` directory.  It contains configuration that is needed on startup (like `fstab`) as well as configuration that can be changed (like `passwd`).

I'm not sure what my best option for moving forward.  Could I have a default `/etc` directory and mount over it after boot?  How about symlink all the variable configuration files to the read/write partition?  Another better solution?  For simplicity, consider how this would be done using a Raspberry Pi.

Some might (rightly) ask how updates are handled.  Updates are compressed and signed images of the root and boot partitions the embedded software know how to install.  Hence the desire for a read-only root file system as any changes would be lost on upgrade.

Comment: QNAP manages this by building the root filesystem (including `/etc`) in RAM, and then having symlinks for editable files back into read/write flash. Could that approach work for you?

Comment: @roaima Depends if I get the RAM back after the boot has finished.  Could not find much anything about how this is done.  Do you have a link with some additional reading?

Comment: I was simply thinking that your RO filesystem would contain links into a RW storage. You wouldn't necessarily need to run in RAM

Comment: Had a similar issue for an embedded product, but didn't bother with a RO fs. Instead I used an initramfs with a small fs in NAND mounted at /home. Symbolic links to files in NAND were used for those files that were update-able or for system configuration. If anything in the ramfs got clobbered, then a reboot restored it.

Comment: @sawdust Is there anything you could point me to that outlines your process (or similar) in more detail?

Comment: @roaima I am having difficulty picturing what you are suggesting.  Could you point to an example?

Comment: @A.Que I think roaima and sawdust meant you have an mostly normal /etc on your read-only root partition but instead of a file /etc/passwd you have a link `/etc/passwd -> /writable-mount/etc/passwd`. Same for any other file or directory in etc which should be changeable.

Comment: Yes exactly, @PaulPazderski

Answer (score 2):

I have two feasible options for you. The first is rather difficult. The second should be easy if you can use btrfs.

### initramfs

A typical way to boot Linux today is by using an [initramfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.html#what-is-initramfs). It is basically a minimal rootfs having only what is needed to mount the real rootfs. The binaries and configurations are packed into an archive stored under /boot and on system start unpacked in a tmpfs as first rootfs.

This means you can have a boot process where a temporary rootfs is loaded from an archive you can modify where the kernel will call an executable called init which you can modify which is intended to mount the real root and doing other system startup stuff.

For a more detailed explanation of this part you can read for example the [Arch boot process](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_boot_process). (especially part 5 (initramfs) and 6 (Early userspace))

Your chance: the initramfs could be anything and do anything. The [Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs) give you a glance on what is possible.
The bad part: it is not easy. The normal way is to use some tools to create an initramfs like `initramfs-tools` on Debian or `mkinitcpio` for Arch or `dracut` or others. They have configuration options but having a separate /etc is to special.

For `initramfs-tools` (I don't know the other tools) it could be feasible to add your own mount /etc stuff. Debian typical `initramfs-tools` are basically a bunch of shell scripts packing a early init which is also just a shell script.

The tooling has hooks which can be used to add custom files to the initramfs (the name hook can be a bit misleading; those are run by `update-initramfs` when creating a new initrafs usually after a kernel update) and scripts which are executed on different points in the early userspace init (again a kinda misleading name because those are something I would call hook).

Good luck if you take this route. If you want an initramfs under Debian you can extract one (they are at /boot/initrd.image*) with the `unmkinitramfs` command and research how other tools integrate there, e.g. `dropbear-initramfs`.

### Btrfs

Another much simpler option is to use btrfs as root filesystem. If using btrfs is an option for you you can utilize its subvolume feature which can be made read-only.

A btrfs subvolume can be mounted like a separate filesystem but the good part for you it does not need to. Mounting a subvolume will automatically mount all subvolume below.

You can quite simply make /etc a separate subvolume¹. After an installation you would do something like

```
mv /etc /etc-tmp
btrfs subvolume create /etc
mv /etc-tmp/* /etc-tmp/.* /etc
rmdir /etc-tmp
```

Now you have /etc in a different subvolume than everything else, you can make the root subvolume read-only with the following command and /etc remains writable.

```
btrfs property set -t subvol / ro true
```

---

¹<sub>By the way: the same approach can be used to make /usr read-only. Always funny if you move the existing /usr away, create the subvolume and then when you want to move the content back you are greeted with a "mv: command not found" because your /usr/bin is currently empty.</sub>

Comment: I am still looking into the first suggestion--initramfs (as you said) is a bit complex--but that might work the best.  The second option is more complected.  For upgrades I would typically just `dd` over the root partition device and reboot.  With `btrfs` subvolumes I would have to restore a snapshot and move the root file system.  Seems like it would be as messy as the first option.

Comment: True. The benefit of the second option, that it is more or less one filesystem and one partition is indeed a problem when you want to "dd replace" the partition and keep a part of the existing.